# ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto, me saca MongoError: Too many positional (i.e. '$')?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

Quiero modificar los nombre de estaciones de este objeto [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Éste es mi código el problema es que estoy obteniendo este error:

> MongoError: Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path '0.$.values.$.stationName'

```
TrainLineDao
      .update(
        {$or: [
          {'0.values.stationId': stationId}, {'1.values.stationId': stationId},
          {'2.values.stationId': stationId}, {'3.values.stationId': stationId},
          {'4.values.stationId': stationId}, {'5.values.stationId': stationId},
          {'6.values.stationId': stationId}
        ]},
        { $set: {
            '0.$.values.$.stationName': query.name, '1.$.values.$.stationName': query.name,
            '2.$.values.$.stationName': query.name, '3.$.values.$.stationName': query.name,
            '4.$.values.$.stationName': query.name, '5.$.values.$.stationName': query.name,
            '6.$.values.$.stationName': query.name
          }
        },
        {multi: true}
      )
      .exec((err, updated) => {
        err ? reject(err)
          : resolve(updated);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hasta la fecha es una limitación de MongoDB, solo puedes usar un operador. En MongoDB 3.5.12 está [planeado](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831) implementar esta característica.

Por el momento debes recorrer los documentos y hacer una condicional para cada uno y así saber a qué nombre actualizar.